# Syntax highlighting on SO/SE

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

The prettifyier, assuming I used it correctly,

```
<pre class="prettyprint"><code>int main(void) { }</code></pre>
```

does not highlight text in the preview box when writing up a question/answer:

`int main(void) { }`

Is this intentional?

(I'll submit this question just to see if it works afterwards, heh.)

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you want to highlight the HTML or the C part?

Comment: Make sure your question is tagged with the correct language. Have you got an example of this? Plus syntax highlighting doesn't need to work here on meta.

Comment: @ChrisF: Well... a lot of people post GreaseMonkey scrips here on Meta.

Comment: @George - I forgot about that aspect. Just take out the word "need" from my comment then ;)

Comment: @ChrisF: "highlighting doesn't to work here on meta" - makes no sense :)

Comment: @George - OK, OK I give up - take "need *to* " out then ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indent your code by four spaces (or by clicking the <kbd>{ }</kbd> button) to enable syntax highlighting. Entering the raw HTML will have the `<pre>` tag stripped because it does not conform to the [strict permitted HTML rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed).

Comment: `<pre>` will *not* be striped: it is in the list of allowed tabs (but no attributes allowed).

Comment: @Richard "You must enter the tags **exactly** as shown. **Any deviation** from this list (adding extra spaces, using single quote or no quotes, etc) means the tag will be stripped." (emphasis mine) - the OP of this question specifically mentioned that s/he was entering `<pre class="prettyprint">`, which would result in the entire tag getting stripped.